# Vuex - store state Object is of type unknown

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

/src/middlewares/auth.ts file:

```
import store from '@/store'

export default {
  guest(): void {
    if (store.state.auth.authenticated === false) {
      // do some action
    }
  }
}
```

/src/store.ts file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    auth
  }
})
```

/src/store/auth.ts:

```
import { Module, VuexModule, Mutation, Action } from 'vuex-module-decorators'

@Module
export default class Auth extends VuexModule {
  public authenticated: boolean = false
}
```

However i'm getting TS error: `Object is of type 'unknown'`

Then my `npm run build` fails. How can i type `store` so this error would disappear?

**UPDATE 1**

Problems is in line: `if (store.state.auth.authenticated === false)`

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

My directory structure for these 3 files:

- /src/middlewares/auth.ts
- /src/store.ts
- /src/store/auth.ts

**UPDATE 3**

if i change `store.state.auth.authenticated` to `store.state` then compiler stops complaining, i think its related to my store auth.ts file, i need to type definition it somehow.

Comment: Can you provide more context and indicate the line of the error? There is not enough code to reproduce the error.

Comment: @tony19 updated my question.

Comment: What does your directory / file structure look like, at least for these two files?

Comment: @Phil, updated post, how it can be related to a paths? Running locally - it shows these errors, but it works, i cannot build for production, due these errors.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you didn't have a `store` directory or `store.js` file that might be getting loaded in place of `store.ts`

Comment: This might help ~ https://codeburst.io/vuex-and-typescript-3427ba78cfa8

Comment: @Phil, i'm using vuex-module-decorators.

Comment: You are not importing the `auth` module

Comment: @roliroli I would have assumed that would throw a totally different error in the `store.ts` file but you're right, it is suspiciously missing from the code above

Comment: Humour me and change your import to `import store from '@/store.ts'`. It's best to not make your build system guess between `src/store.ts` (the file) and `src/store` (the directory)

Comment: I came across exactly the same issue after installing my dependencies from scratch. I solved it by declaring 'state' as type 'any': `import store from '@/store.ts' ... const state = store.state as any;`. I wouldn't go so far as calling this a clean solution, but at least my code compiles now.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: [logrocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/vue-middleware-pipelines/)

```
export default function auth ({ next, store }){
 if(!store.getters.auth.loggedIn){
     return next({
        name: 'login'
     })
 }

 return next()
}
```

Your first argument sohuld be an object defining { store }

```
export default guest ({ store }, to: any ...){
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell where `store` comes from in your scenario that you posted. If you are importing it directly then it would be something along the lines of:

```js
import store from "store/index";
```

Also, by the nature of the store it's not fully typed. You could type it with something like

```js
if ((store as object).state?.auth?.isLogged) {}
```

Though this won't give you type safety it would tell the compiler that you don't know.